# How does NDT work with global bundle adjustment?

Tags: slam, lidar, ba

I was reading about pointcloud matching and SLAM.

NDT is one approach to scan matching, what I am confused on is how you do global bundle adjustment using NDT occupancy grid.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4045903_The_Normal_Distributions_Transform_A_New_Approach_to_Laser_Scan_Matching

The thing which is confusing is basically your NDT is with respect to the global coordinates and doesn't appear to be relative to each scan.

Comment: Any of the scan registration techniques such as NDT, ICP, etc. can be in the local or global or any other coordinate system. I am not sure why you assume NDT is fixed to the global. Can you give more details of your work and/or code to help us understand your issue?

Comment: The paper discusses the mapping as expanding the map continuously using a common grid(I think).  For bundle adjustment would each key frame create its own grid structure?